A Suspicious Criminal Confounds A Superhero Conference Committee
Every year, The League of Freedom, Earth's foremost superhero team, holds a conference to discuss crime fighting strategies and potential threats. Every year, tryouts are held in order to select this year's candidate for the League's unpaid internship, but this year, the league has been tipped off that The Illusionist, a powerful supervillain, has infiltrated the pool of candidates.
The league has narrowed it down to just a handful of candidates. Ruby Dude, the Gem Detective, has asked two of this year's candidates, Cornerstone and Hour-Lass, to test the suspects powers to see if they are truly who they say they are.
Cornerstone and Hour-Lass together have all six powers that the suspects have, each possessing the 3 that the other doesn't have. Each of the five heros in turn showed each of their three powers, one after the other. So, can you determine the three powers each hero has, what order they decided to show their own powers in, and what three powers the Illusionist did NOT display, and most importantly, can you figure out which of these heros is actually the Illusionist in disguise?
Below are six clues to help you:

The five people are: The person who decided to show Strength as their second power, The only two people who can Teleport, The person who showed their three powers last, and The Duck Defender.

Cornerstone went first. His first power he displayed was Flight. After his demonstration, the next time Flight was displayed was in exactly ten displays of power. Hour-Lass went second. Her third power she displayed was Laser Vision. After her demonstration, the next time Laser Vision was displayed was in exactly eight displays of power.

Delivery Guy was impressed by the person who went before him. Their third power was the same as his first power. After Delivery Guy showed off his first power, they didn't seem impressed, so his second power he chose to display was one they did not have.

Exactly one of the following three statements is true about Mega Hawk: Invisibility was her first displayed power; Laser Vision was her first displayed power; Cornerstone's third displayed power was Mega Hawk's second power. Regardless of which of the three statements is true, the previous time the power in the correct statement was seen was exactly five displays of power before Mega Hawk displayed it.

Exactly two of the following statements are true: The person who displayed Laser Vision as their second power also showed Flight as their third power; Mega Hawk was the third hero to display their powers and her second displayed power was Strength; The first time the Bullet Proof power was displayed and the second time the Bullet Proof power was displayed were separated by exactly one display of power.

The Duck Defender did not display Invisibility as his first power.


Note: "Not The Illusionist" is not a hero. Those are the three powers that the Illusionist does NOT have.
The puzzle is solvable by using the 6 clues above and the preamble. However, if you need a hint, I will provide five below. The hints progressively reveal steps in the puzzle, so if you need them, click from top to bottom.

 1. Not The Illusionist's first power is Laser Vision.


 2. Duck Defender can either be the 3rd or 4th person, Delivery Guy can either be the 4th or 5th person, Mega Hawk can either be the 3rd, 4th, or 5th person.


 3. If you work through hint 2's scenarios, they will create contradictions except for the correct one. Find those contradictions and the clues will help you solve the rest fairly quickly.


 4. Mega Hawk is not person 4. A contradictions can be found by comparing Clue 4 with Duck Defender and Hour-Lass's second power.


 5. Mega Hawk is not person 3. The contradictions come mostly from how Clues 4 and 5 interact with Cornerstone's third power.

Can you figure it out?

Also, this is a logic grid puzzle, so all standard logic grid rules apply (i.e. Each row and each Column in a section has exactly 1 correct cell.)
As with all of my logic grid puzzles, please tell me what you liked/disliked about this puzzle so that I can continue to improve making them.
Also, if the grammar in any of the clues are confusing, let me know and I'll either explain it in the comments or update the clue to be more clear.
Thanks for trying out my puzzle. I hope you enjoy it.

Can SAT-solvers/brute force be used?

As a non-native english speaker, the introduction is a bit hard to follow. 1) Why is the tests done by Cornerstone and Hour-Lass if they are themselves part of the suspects ? 2) Why isn't the fact that thoses 2 have all 6 power combined part of the clues ? 3) the sentence "Each of the five heros in turn showed each of their three powers, one after the other" could mean that "each superhero shows one power, waiting a full circle before showing the second power", or that "each superhero shows all three of their power at once, then the next one does".

I have no idea what SAT-solvers/brute force is. I'm sure you could brute force it, but that's not really solving it.

Answering each in turn. 1) Because I came up with the puzzle first and then thought about the preamble. It's a story for a logic puzzle. There are going to be plot holes. My thoughts is that Cornerstone and Hour-Lass are not suspects, they are only testing the suspects, however, if one of them is the Illusionist, then the detective got lucky that he asked the Illusionist to be involved in the test. 2) Because that's how preamble clues work. That fact used to be part of clue 2, but I didn't want to repeat it. 3) Look at clues 2 and 3. Only 1 way of thinking about how they did their tests work

I thought about it and wanted to add something else. 1) The preamble says that the Illusionist infiltrated the pool of candidates. Therefore, any candidate has the possibility of being the Illusionist. So if CS or HL are the Illusionist, the story is still consistent. A suspect is not necessarily a guilty person, and a non-suspect is not necessarily innocent. 2) I always include preamble clues. My logic puzzles are not meant to be easy. Preamble clues are one way to achieve this. So, as with the previous 2 puzzles I made, the preamble contains clues and is needed for solving.

Thank you for answering. It was more about comprehension for myself that finding plot holes. 1) Ok it's clear that any of the 5 candidates could be the illusionist, and CS and HL are not specials. 2) Ok, I was wondering if it implied something more general about superpowers repartition, but I'll just use it as another clue. 3) Ok, I'll check the clues to see which one it is. Thank you again for taking the time to answer :)

The Illusionist is

 Cornerstone

and the order of powers is

 1. Cornerstone: flight, strength, invisibility
 2. Hour-Lass: teleport, bullet proof, laser vision
 3. Duck Defender: bullet proof, invisibility, strength
 4. Delivery Guy: strength, flight, teleport
 5. Mega Hawk: invisibility, laser vision, flight
 Not the Illusionist: laser vision, teleport, bullet proof


Solution path:

 Using the second clue, we can deduce:
 1. Cornerstone: flight, (not laser vision), (not laser vision)
 2. Hour-Lass: (not flight), (not flight), laser vision
 3. No flight, no laser vision
 4. ?, flight, ?; no laser vision
 5. ?, laser vision, ?

 From the first clue, we also know that 5. is not Duck Defender. One of Cornerstone or Hour-Lass must know Teleport, and the other Teleporter is the one who is not Duck Defender or last in the list.
 My natural next step was to start tackling the scenarios of clue 5, first assuming that the first statement was false -- but I got pretty far before that ended up with Mega Hawk having to know teleport as the one who wasn't Duck Defender or the last hero, AND having to know strength as her second power, which contradicted with clue 1. At this point I decided to be lazy and just check out the spoilered hints. Those immediately give you:
 1. Cornerstone: flight, (not laser vision), (not laser vision)
 2. Hour-Lass: (not flight), (not flight), laser vision
 3. Duck Defender: (not invisibility), ?, ?; No flight, no laser vision
 4. Delivery Guy: ?, flight, ?; no laser vision, can teleport
 5. Mega Hawk: ?, laser vision, ?

 Now, we know that the second statement in clue 5 (Mega Hawk is 3.) is the false one. From the third statement in clue 5, we can deduce that the first time bullet proof was displayed had to be by Hour-Lass as her second, as her third was laser vision, and then Duck Defender takes up the next display as his first. From the first statement, in clue 5, Mega Hawk's third power must be flight. We also know that the second and third statements in clue 4 are false (that Mega Hawk's first power was laser vision, and that Cornerstone's third power is laser vision), so her first power must be invisibility, matching Duck Defender's second power:
 1. Cornerstone: flight, (not laser vision), (not laser vision)
 2. Hour-Lass: (not flight), bullet proof, laser vision
 3. Duck Defender: bullet proof, invisibility, ?; no flight, no laser vision
 4. Delivery Guy: ?, flight, ?; no laser vision, can teleport
 5. Mega Hawk: invisibility, laser vision, flight

 Only two people can teleport, and one of them is Cornerstone or Hour-Lass, so Delivery Guy's third ability must be teleport. Duck Defender's third power is Delivery Guy's first, so Delivery Guy's third power must be teleport. From process of elimination we can get Duck Defender's third and Delivery Guy's first (not flight, laser vision, teleport, bullet proof, invisibility):
 1. Cornerstone: flight, (not laser vision), (not laser vision)
 2. Hour-Lass: (not flight), bullet proof, laser vision
 3. Duck Defender: bullet proof, invisibility, strength
 4. Delivery Guy: strength, flight, teleport
 5. Mega Hawk: invisibility, laser vision, flight

 Filling out Cornerstone and Hour-Lass by process of elimination -- they can't share the same power and order as anyone else, and they can't share powers among themselves:
 1. Cornerstone: flight, strength, invisibility
 2. Hour-Lass: teleport, bullet proof, laser vision
 3. Duck Defender: bullet proof, invisibility, strength
 4. Delivery Guy: strength, flight, teleport
 5. Mega Hawk: invisibility, laser vision, flight

 Finally, we get Not the Illusionist's powers by process of elimination:
 1. Cornerstone: flight, strength, invisibility
 2. Hour-Lass: teleport, bullet proof, laser vision
 3. Duck Defender: bullet proof, invisibility, strength
 4. Delivery Guy: strength, flight, teleport
 5. Mega Hawk: invisibility, laser vision, flight
 Not the Illusionist: laser vision, teleport, bullet proof

 This means the Illusionist had flight, strength, and invisibility -- which exactly matches Cornerstone.

